# Запрос cURL возвращает ошибку

Tags: php, curl

На хостинге обращаюсь к сайту, с целью получения json ответа.
На локальной машине curl все возвращает, на хостинге - Curl failed with error #7: couldn't connect to host.

В чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Надо проверить что сайт доступен с сервера. ping, nslookup или любой другой способ.

Если нет - проверить что какой-либо точно работающий сайт доступен с сервера.

Если и это не работает - обратитесь к хостеру, какая-то проблема с сетью.